# Reducing binomial fraction when equivalent numerator or denominator has inverted signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through some basic Algebra problems trying to refresh my rusty math skills. I was confused by a fraction reduction problem. The problem is to divide the following:

$$\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} \div \frac{a-3}{4}$$

After factoring this yields:

$$\frac{(a-3)^2}{a(a+3)} \times \frac{4}{a-3}$$

after reducing this yields:

$$\frac{a-3}{a(a+3)} \times \frac{4}{1}$$

The answer is $\frac{4}{a}$, however from the rules that I've reviewed so far I don't understand how $(a-3)$ and $(a+3)$ cancel out on a fractional reduction given that they have different signs. I feel like I'm missing something basic on this problem, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake you made was in factorizing $a^2-9$. I think this is just likely a simple mistake as $(a-3)^2 = a^2-6a+9 \neq a^2 -9$. So getting from your first line to your second line should be like so:

$\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} = \frac{(a-3)(a+3)}{a^2+3a} $

After that point it's just a matter of simplifying.

Comment: Yes that explains it, I didn't see a trinomial which is why I made that dumb factoring mistake, thanks!